# Trend or Shift Detection in python?

Tags: python

Is there any library which detects trends and shift in data automatically in python, I have searched on the internet but could not find any library.

Nor I have found any working examples, I found some papers but they weren't that helpful.

So if anyone knows a library or practical implementation for pls do suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/)? Self-description:

> "SciPy (pronounced “Sigh Pie”) is a Python-based ecosystem of open-source software for mathematics, science, and engineering."

There is also a tutorial about [detrending data](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_detrend.html) with scipy.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

n = 150
t = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
x_raw = .4 * t + np.random.normal(size=n)

x = signal.detrend(x_raw)

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
plt.plot(t, x_raw, label="Raw data")
plt.plot(t, x, label="After Trend Removal")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update:**

Sadly there is no argument for `signaltools.detrend` to directly get the trend. Of course, one could simple edit the method or do a linear regression by hand.

But the quickest way to implement this seems to be this:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

n = 150
t = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
x_raw = .4 * t + np.random.normal(size=n)

x = signal.detrend(x_raw)
d = x_raw - x

is_positive_trend = d[-1] > d[0]
m = "+" if is_positive_trend else "-"

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
plt.plot(t, x_raw, label=f"Raw data ({m})")
plt.plot(t, d)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Calulate the delta `d = x_raw - x` between raw data and detrended data. The trend is positive, when the last *x*-value is larger than the first: `is_positive_trend = d[-1] > d[0]`

[image]

Comment: I don't want to remove the trend I want to know which trend it is up trend or down trend.

Comment: Cool approach, thanks.